# Laravel 6.2 : I get the same Id from different data in index() method

Tags: php, mysql, database, eloquent, laravel-6.2

I work with Laravel and I need to get some reservations from my database.

I use the query builder :

```
 public function getReservation($date)
    {
        $reservations = DB::table('reservations')
                        ->select('*')
                        ->join('agendas', 'reservations.agenda_id', '=', 'agendas.id')
                        ->whereDate('arrivee', $date)
                        ->get();

        return response($reservations);
    }
```

Everything is fine except that I have the same ID for different resource and I don't know why ?

the response :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2020-02-07 12:30:28",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-07 12:30:28",
        "arrivee": "2020-02-12 13:00:00",
        "nbre_client": 4,
        "num_table": null,
        "remarque": null,
        "venu": 0,
        "formule": 0,
        "agenda_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "nom_client": "Stark",
        "prenom_client": null,
        "num_phone_client": "0658180058",
        "email_client": null,
        "confirmResa": null,
        "nameAg": "London"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2020-02-07 12:30:28",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-07 12:30:28",
        "arrivee": "2020-02-12 13:30:00",
        "nbre_client": 2,
        "num_table": null,
        "remarque": null,
        "venu": 0,
        "formule": 0,
        "agenda_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "nom_client": "Banner",
        "prenom_client": null,
        "num_phone_client": "0658180058",
        "email_client": null,
        "confirmResa": null,
        "nameAg": "London"
    }
]
```

The ID in my database are different (Respectively 2 and 3)

Any ideas someone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

The duplicated ids is most likely the id from your `agendas` since they belong to the same agenda.

You could change your select to:

```php
->select('reservations.*')
```

### The Eloquent Way

You could also accomplish what you have with Eloquent.

First, you need to make sure you `Reservation` model has a `BelongsTo` relation with your `Agenda` model.

```php
public function agenda()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Agenda::class);
}
```

Then you can query it like this:

```php
Reservation::whereHas('agenda', function ($query) use ($date) {
    $query->whereDate('arrivee', $date);
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks ! And what are the best pratice ? Query builder or Eloquent way ?

Comment: @JoLeBelge I personally prefer using Eloquent, since it simplifies a lot. But they are both good. The "best practice" might be opinion based.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! The both works correctly so I'm going to try the most simply for me...